# Inverses of generating elements of a group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $S$ be a subset of $G$ and denote $S^{-1}$ the set of inverses of elements of $S$. Then by definition, $S$ is a generating set of $G$ if any $g\in G$ is a finite product of elements of $S$ and their inverses. My question is about the reason of  including inverses $S^{-1}$ of $S$ into the definition of a generating set. Couldn't we just define it as the product of elements of $S$ without talking about elements of $S^{-1}$ or if it is necessary define $S\cup S^{-1}$ as the generating set not only $S$ ? For example the group $\mathbb Z$ would be generated by $1$ **and** $-1$ so $2=1+1$ and $-2=(-1)+(-1)$ hence if $-1$ is not an element of the generating set then $-2$ can't be written as a sum of ones.  thank you for your clarification !

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that the subgroup generated by $S$ should be the smallest subgroup of $G$ that contains $S$; or, more formally, the intersection of all subgroups of $G$ that contain $S$. I think that is a better definition of $\langle S \rangle$. You can then prove that this subgroup is equal to the set of all products of elements from $S$ and from $S^{-1}$ (including the empty product if $S$ is empty).

If you just take the set of all products of elements of $S$ then the resulting set is not necessarily a subgroup of $G$. You get the submonoid (if you include the empty product) or subsemigroup (if not) of $G$ generated  by $S$.

Of course, for finite groups (or more generally for torsion groups) you need only take products of elements of $S$ to get a subgroup.

Comment: I'm confused by how the definition is phrased. Take for example, an infinite group $G$ and it's subset $S= \{x, y, z\}$ so it's set of all products is $\{x^i y^j z^k : i,j,k \in \mathbb{Z}_+ \}$, the obvious problem is that it has no identity and no inverse so that's why we also include elements of $S^{-1}$, am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: No, its the subset of all products of arbitrary length, such as $xyxxzyxzyzx$ or $zzyzyyyyz$,  including the empty product. So it does contain the identity (the empty product), but you are right that it does not always contain inverses of all elements.

Comment: Wait no to what? Did i interpret the definition of $S$ wrong? Can I not just write $zzyzyyyyz= z^2yzy^4z$? Or did you say "no" to my "identity doesn't belong" to $S$?

Comment: I meant no it is not the set of all products $\{x^iy^jz^k : i,j,k \in {\mathbb Z}_+ \}$. Even the element $yx$ does not necessarily lie in that set.

Comment: Oh, that was embarrassing. Sorry haha. I suppose saying saying the product of elements of $S$ is simpler. Also why talk about inverses at all? Wouldn't it be *nicer* to just say "product of integral powers of elements of $S$"? Or is there a flaw with this too?